# Is passing SelectListItems via ViewData preventing the selected value from being recognised?

Tags: html.dropdownlistfor, mvc-editor-templates, selectedvalue, selectlistitem

I had this `DropDownListFor()` in a view and it worked as expected:

**View**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Item.Starsign)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Item.Title)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Item.Name)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item.ShoeID, 
    Model.ShoeOptions, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Result**

```
<option value="1">Nike Trainers</option>
<option value="2">Slippers</option>
<option selected="selected" value="3">Western Boots</option>
<option value="4">Asics Runner</option>
```

---

Then I moved it into a separate `EditorTemplate`, and *the current value of the ShoeID property is no longer selected*.

**View**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Item.Starsign)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Item.Title)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Item.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Item.ShoeID, 
    new { options = Model.ShoeOptions })
```

**EditorTemplate**

```
@model int
@{
    List<SelectListItem> options = ViewData["options"] as List<SelectListItem>;
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, options, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Result**

```
<option value="1">Nike Trainers</option>
<option value="2">Slippers</option>
<option value="3">Western Boots</option><!-- this should be selected, but isn't -->
<option value="4">Asics Runner</option>
```

---

It appears that passing the `List<SelectListItem>` via ViewData prevents it from matching the ShoeID property with the correct item from the list of options.

Is that what's happening or am I missing something?

Comment: I cannot duplicate this behavior. The correct option is selected when using the `EditorTemplate` (although i does seem a bit stannge that you have created an template for typeof `int`). Are you sure the value of `ShoeID` is `3` in the second example?

Comment: Strange... I will relook at it to be sure.  The template's function is "display a drop down of these options" - where the options are an additional property on the VM, and the selected option is an `int`.

Comment: I take that back. My test was creating using an `EditorTemplate` for `Item` and using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item, Model.ShoeOptions)` which does work fine. But if its for `int` and using `m => m.Item.ShoeID`, the correct item is not selected. But why would you be creating an `EditorTemplate` for `int` that creates a `<select>` (it would mean every property in your model that is `int` would generate a `<select>`)?

Comment: I have a standard `int` template for `int` properties.  Rather this template is declared using `[UIHint("DropDownListWithViewDataOptions")]` but the model type is set to `int` because the choice will be applied to the `ShoeID` property of `Item`.  I did wonder if there is a better way, but perhaps one for a separate question.